Led blinking with STM32F103RET6
I have a Micro STM32F103RET6 And although I manage to turn on an LED by the PB13, I can not get it to blink, when I remove the call to the function SystemClock_Config(), turn on the LED, it also does not blink and when I put it or turn on the led, I think the problem is in the clock configuration, I present that I did, to see if anyone can find the error.

int main(void) {
  HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();

  while (1) {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(led1_GPIO_Port, led1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET); //p13 
    HAL_Delay(500);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(led1_GPIO_Port, led1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET); //p13
    HAL_Delay(500);
    //HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(led1_GPIO_Port,led1_Pin);
  }
}

void SystemClock_Config(void) {
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {
    0
  };
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {
    0
  };

  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEPredivValue = RCC_HSE_PREDIV_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL9;

  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig( & RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK |
    RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig( & RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}


Did you try running it with the debugger and see what happens? Single step through your code? Do you, in fact, end up in Error_Handler()? Your code seems to enable the PLL, but you don't really configure it.

Do you enable the sysTick interrupt? If not, functions like HAL_Delay() will not work (and will just never return).
